# UITableView with different cells "behavior"

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm developing a location-aware application as a project for the university and one of the feature to develop consists of showing the first five points of interest closest to the user. I'm using a table view whose cells style is UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle. I'm having some problems because beyond the title and subtitle of the cell i'm using an image (arrow) to show the direction which the user should follow to reach the POI. This image should rotate as soon as the heading/position of the device change. The problem is that only the last row of the table view works and the main problem is that I don't figure out how to use five different cells since each POI can have a different position rather the position of the device thereby each cell's image should rotate independently.
I report an image to give a better understanding of my problem.

[image: TableView]

Here follows the code I used for the tableview cells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *tableIdentifier = @"tableIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:tableIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];


    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance: %.3f Km",[...];

    UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];
    cell.imageView.image = cellImage;
    self.cellImageView = cell.imageView;

    return cell;
}
```

Any ideas of how to use 5 different cells in order to provide each arrow with its right angle?!

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell me how you added heading for UIImageView. You can share your code here. I will give your answer soon.

Comment: How do you update your cells?

Comment: In the view controller of the table view I defined a property for a UIImageView that it will be updated as soon as the device change its heading. In the method above the outlet is initialized through self.cellImageView = cell.imageView; When the device change its heading the delegate update the imageView using a CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing:

`self.cellImageView = cell.imageView`.

You are giving yourself a reference only to the very last of the cells. Each time a cell is configured, your `cellImageView` variable gets updated to point to that cell's image view and you lose your reference to the previous **cell's image view**.

So, one way of solving your problem is to accumulate the cell image views in an array. Just make sure you keep the image view matched up with the appropriate location; cells can get reused as the tableview displays. But the tableview owns those cells and can mess with them however it wants for caching purposes (hence the reuse identifier).

A better way would be to cooperate with the tableview and let it know when things need changing. Forget about your ivar, and just set the correct heading during cell configuration. Need to change the heading for a cell? Tell the tableview to reload that cell. Need to change the headings for all cells? Just call `[[self tableView] reloadData]`.

Only if you run into issues with noticeable UI slowdowns should you worry about doing something more clever.

Comment: Does reloadData execute the method tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath? If so within this method I can call a function to calculate the angle of transformation so each time reloadData is called the function is called and the images are updated. Do you think that in this way work?

Comment: Yes, it does call that method. So you can just call `reloadData` when the location/heading changes, then check the correct direction for that index path and rig up the cell appropriately.